Using PHP and SQL, How do i tell if value exists in DB?
I am using Vtiger crm. I have a field where i want users to input Bin_numbers (in e-commerce you can call it product number). But i want this field to only accept Bin numbers that already exist in the database and rejects wrong numbers.
Its supposed to be a vtiger workflow function. I have created the workflow but the code i wrote isn't working. Can someone please help with a good code. I am not so good with php and sql
I have tried doing this:

<?php
// Include necessary Vtiger files
require_once('include/events/include.inc');
require_once('include/utils/utils.php');

// Custom validation function for Bin Number field in Job module
function validateFormField($input) {
    // Query the database to check if the input value exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_bins WHERE binsid = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$input]);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    // Check if a row was returned
    if($result) {
        // Process the input further if needed
        return "Input accepted!";
    } else {
        // Reject the input if it doesn't exist in the database
        return "The bin number doesn't exist. Please call us.";
    }
}


$inputValue = $_POST['cf_1052']; // Assuming 'fieldName' is the name of your form field
$result = validateFormField($inputValue);
echo $result;
?>


Your code isn't working in what way? It generates a PHP error message? If so, please put it in your question. Did you check for error messages at all? If not, do so. If the code fails in some way, or doesn't do what you expect, please describe this problem in as much detail as you can.

Just looking at your code, it seems that $pdo isn't known inside your validateFormField() function. Either use it as an argument to the function or use global $pdo;. This should have generated an easy to understand PHP error message. Have a look here: Display error messages

@KIKOSoftware The code isn't working in the sense that it is accepting any number that is inputted. it seems not to compare what's in database with what the user has inputted. Although, it displays the word 'error' but still accepts the wrong number when you try again. I explicitly want it to reject the wrong bin numbers and display the error message i put there.
Furthermore, i used PDO as global and still the same. And switched it as an argument and nothing changed

Nothing in the code, that is in the question, could only output the word "error". There must be some other code, you're not showing, that does this.

Sincerely, that is all the code i pasted. Except vtiger has another code that is blocking this one. This code can only be invoked using the vtiger's workflow module.  and Other vtiger workflows I have implemented works normally so I can say that I fully understand how vtiger workflows work but when I select the option of using a custom workflow function and direct it to this my code, it doesn't do what I expect
